# VIM: how to set "errorformat" in my specified error message format?

Tags: string, file, vim, build, errorformat

In my system, we re-formatted all the build error message to have this format:

```
[2016-02-10 13:17:56.885597]    [WARNING]   [53171] [src/root/mylinux/test01.cpp:300]
```

As you could see, this format contain several parts:

```
1. The time stamp, day+hour+minute+second+microsecond
2. Some spaces and the [WARNING] or [ERROR] or [INFO] or [DEBUG], etc.
3. A process ID number like [53171]
4. The source file name + line number
```

I wish to use vim+quickfix to open this build error file, and navigate to source files+line number. So how to set 'errorformat' string in my .vimrc?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a relatively unpleasant thing to parse with `errorformat` to be sure, but you can do if you insist.  One possible approach:

```
let &errorformat = '[%m]%*[ ][%t%*[A-Z]]%*[ ][%n]%*[ ][%f:%l]'
```